Generating a different zipcode after each spawn in unity
Sorry for terrible grammar but I've been working on a Conveyor Belt project for the past month and been having problems with the parcels(Boxes) not having specific zip code after each spawn. I'm still kinda new to Unity and C#.
The goal that I'm trying to reach is to have parcel with a different zip code each time it spawns. I'm able to spawn the parcel and I am able to implement zip code however it's the same zip code with the same box. I have 4 different boxes(box-long, bow-wide, box-small, box-large) and 4 different zip codes(30190, 46675, 01075, 24701). Say for example box-long = 30190 and then box-long spawns again but this time it's 46675. The issue in this case is that box-long would have the zip code 30190 every time it spawns.
What I tried to do is implement different Lists, one being for zip codes(int) and the other being for Boxes(GameObject) but doing that seems to make more things complicated than it had to be. Another solution was to implement a dictionary with both Boxes and zip codes together but I'm afraid doing that was making specific zip codes go into specific boxes every time it spawns. I know this might seem random but I tried using the fisher-yates shuffle algorithm to specifically shuffle the zip codes every time the parcel spawns but it didn't work :(
public class Parcel : MonoBehaviour{
    List<GameObject> DifferentBoxes = new List<GameObject>(); /*A list that contains
    different parcel GameObjects. This list will contain the GameObjects that will be'
    be used throughout the Conveyor*/
    
    List<int> ZipCode = new List<int>();

    public GameObject boxLong; //Connected to the box-long asset in the scene
    public GameObject boxWide; //Connected to the box-wide asset in the scene
    public GameObject boxLarge; //Connected to the box-large asset in the scene
    public GameObject boxSmall; //Connected to the box--small asset in the scene
    private Vector3 startingPosition; /*Declaring a specifc spawnPoint in the scene
                                         meaning we want all the parcels to spawn at 
                                         the loading area.*/
                                              
    


// Start is called before the first frame update
private void Start(){

    DifferentBoxes.Add(boxLong); /*Once the scene starts, the parcels will immediately be 
                                    added to the DifferentBoxes list/*/
    DifferentBoxes.Add(boxWide);// <--|
    DifferentBoxes.Add(boxLarge);// <-|
    DifferentBoxes.Add(boxSmall);// <-|
    ZipCode.Add(30190);
    ZipCode.Add(46675);
    ZipCode.Add(01075);
    ZipCode.Add(24701);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update(){

       if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){ //Pressing space makes the box spawn

        RandomBox(); //Calling the RandomBox function to generate a parcel
       }
}

private void RandomBox(){

    int randomize = Random.Range(0, DifferentBoxes.Count); /*Making an int randomize by 
                                                            ranging 0 to the size of the 
                                                            list being 3*/
    GameObject ofSomeBox = DifferentBoxes[randomize]; /*Once we have a randomized number from
                                                        the range, we will use this as an element
                                                        to get a specific parcel from the list. We're
                                                        also declaring this as a Gameobject to ge the
                                                        actual 3D asset.*/
    ofSomeBox.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f); /*Scaling the parcel so it's fits inside 
                                                                     inside the conveyor belt.*/

    SpawnBox(ofSomeBox); /*Calling the SpawnBox function with a GameObject
                            ofSomeBox.*/

}

 public void SpawnBox(GameObject BoxFromOther){ /*This initially was on a seperate 
                                                    script but didn't think it was needed
                                                    because of unecessary code*/
    startingPosition = new Vector3(-2.43f, 0.87f, Random.Range(-0.2f, 1.9f)); /*Making specific coordinates where the parcels 
                                                                                should spawn in the Gameworld. */
    GameObject CreatingBox = Instantiate(BoxFromOther, startingPosition, Quaternion.identity); /*Creating randomized clones of parcels using the 
                                                                        BoxFromOther that was passed from tge SpawnBox function. 
                                                                        We then use the startingPosition coordinates that we made earlier.
                                                                        The last one that we made was was the Quaternion.identity to make no rotation.*/ 
        
     int randomZipIndex = Random.Range(0, ZipCode.Count);
     int ActualZipCode = ZipCode[randomZipIndex];
     



 }

}

One suggestion would be to POST SOME ACTUAL CODE.  Show us what you have tried and what is failing.

I added the code. feel free to look at it. I made a some setbacks a little bit because I tried fixing it with other ideas

where is the code when you set the zipcode to the box? the last code about zipcode is     int ActualZipCode = ZipCode[randomZipIndex]; . the ActualZipCode is unused.

I forgot to reply but I was able to fix it by implying an array of structs. I already knew it was unused because I made a restart on it but I eventually figured it out.\
